# Get created rows for table type parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have fairly simple stored procedure to insert users into user table but what I need is to get all newly created rows or Ids for just inserted entries.

Here is my code.

```
Custom created table type.
use Users;
GO

Drop TYPE IF EXISTS dbo.CustomUser;
Go

create type CustomUser as table
(
    FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    CreatedAt datetimeoffset not null,
    UpdatedAt datetimeoffset not null
);
go

Stored Procedure.
use Users;
GO

Drop PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.InsertUser;
GO

Create PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUser
    (
        @Users CustomUser READONLY
    )
AS
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [User](FirtName, LastName, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt)
        Select FirstName, LastName, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt From @Users

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    end
```

How to get Ids for newly created rows inside stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare table to store `ID's` and then use `OUTPUT` statement to return inserted `ID's`

```
DECLARE @InsertedIds table (ID int not null)
INSERT into User(col1, ....)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @InsertedIds
Select FirstName, LastName, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt From @Users


SELECT * from @InsertedIds
```